# How to get the python command to call python3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, alias, aliases

tl;dr: does anyone know any better way to accomplish basically the same thing as aliases since mine don't work?

hey and thanks for reading,
I have a raspberry pi where I'm trying to run a bot that only works on python 3.6 and up. Python only officially supports up to 3.5 on Raspberry Pi, so I had to manually compile it.
Anyway, the bot I use calls "python3" in its coding, however Raspberry Pis come with 3.5, so calling "python3" actually calls Python 3.5, not 3.7. I tried deleting Python 3.5, but it then rather than calling Python 3.7, it just said that nothing named python3 exists.
I tried using aliases to call it, but they don't work at all for some reason. I know I'm using the right syntax, and I did the update command for the file, but they just don't work.
I know that's kind of a lot, but does anyone know any better way to accomplish basically the same thing as aliases since mine don't work? Or can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my current coding for aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Use a full path to your new python version to run it.

`/full/path/to/3.7/python3.7`

What the path is will depend on the directions you followed and options picked when compiling the new python version.

if you want it to work by simply typing `python` or `python3` you will have to change the symbolic links to point to the new python version.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for responding. I was a little confused by your answer initially as python 3.7.3 was able to be called by just typing "python3.7". However, I tried to figure out how to change the symbolic links to be python3 and python, but before trying to fix it I had to completely redo the bot because of other problems with my pi. Turns out I had installed the script with python 3.5 by accident and tried to run it with 3.7, which obviously proved to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not advisable to install an out-of-distribution Python version, and you can't expect system libraries to work with it.

Your best bet is to upgrade to Raspbian Buster, as it comes with Python 3.7 as standard. Buster is still in testing phase and not due for release until the summer, but I've been using it for a while and it seems to work ok. I have had success upgrading the Lite image but not Desktop.

To upgrade, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `stretch` with `buster`, then  run `apt update; apt dist-upgrade` and wait for it to do the upgrade, then reboot and you'll have `python3` pointing at Python 3.7.

Comment: hey, thanks so much for your answer, but it turned out to actually be pretty stupid on my part lol. python 3.7 is working fine, but the problem was that I only realized I needed python 3.7 after installing the bot, so I installed the bot with 3.5 and then ran it with 3.7, which messed everything up. That sounds like a good update, though. Does it have any other major benefits? (I'll probably look them up but just out of curiosity)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Debian do releases every 2 years, so you get a stable OS that's supported for I think 5 years, and you can expect packages to work if you stick to what's in the distro. With every upgrade comes a wave of new versions of things, e.g. Python 3.5 -> 3.7. The important thing is that it's stable and well supported. See https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster for more info on the release